# Find strings that do not begin with something

Tags: regex

This has been gone over but I've not found anything that works consistently... or assist me in learning where I've gone awry.

I have file names that start with 3 or more digits and `^\d{3}(.*)` works just fine. 
I also have strings that start with the word 'account' and `^ACCOUNT(.*)` works just fine for these.

The problem I have is all the other strings that DO NOT meet the two previous criteria. I have been using `^[^\d{3}][^ACCOUNT](.*)` but occasionally it fails to catch one.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What regex implementation are you using? The javascript one? PCRE (PHP/PERL)? Java? C#?

Comment: To add to what @h2ooooooo asks.  You mention "..occasionally fails to catch one".  It would make tremendous sense to show us examples of which ones fail and which do not.

Comment: I'm using C# and the following are the suject test list:

Comment: I'm using C# and the following are the subject test list: 001_Invoice.pdf, 002_Statement.pdf, Account.pdf, BlahBLahBlah.pdf,Fubar.pdf,Report1.pdf,Report12.pdf. Fubar.pdf is not caught. And let me add my thanks for even looking a this, let alone so startlingly fast.

Comment: In this case I'm not sure the implementation or example where necessary, since the regex is pretty obviously wrong. But indeed @user3228176 this is the kind of stuff you want to include in a well formed question. Also your previous comment is incomplete/really hard to read and we don't see it at first glance: when someone ask for more info you should generally edit your question, so everyone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^\d{3}][^ACCOUNT](.*)
```

That's definitely not what you want. Square brackets create character classes: they match one character from the list of characters in brackets. If you put a `^` then the match is inverted and it matches one character that's *not* listed. The meaning of `^` inside brackets is completely different from its meaning outside.

In short, `[]` is not at all what you want. What you *can* do, if your regex implementation supports it, is use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion.

```
^(?!\d{3}|ACCOUNT)(.*)
```

This negative lookahead assertion doesn't match anything itself. It merely checks that the next part of the string `(.*)` does not match either `\d{3}` or `ACCOUNT`.

Comment: Apparently the C# implementation does support it because the fubar file now appears. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Demorgan's law says: `!(A v B) = !A ^ !B`.

But unfortunately Regex itself does 
*not* support the negation of expressions. (You always could rewrite it, but sometimes, this is a huge task).

Instead, you should look at your Programming Language, where you can negate values without problems:

let the "matching" function be "match" and you are using `match("^(?:\d{3}|ACCOUNT)(.)")` to determine, whether the string matches one of both conditions. Then you could simple negate the boolean return value of that matching function and you'll receive every string that does NOT match.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not true. You can use negative look-ahead `(?! )` to negate every regex you want: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: A negativ Lookahead is not a negation. I just said, Regex does not support negations. I also said, that you can still solve it, when putting in much effort. And negating a complex expression by using negativ lookaheads *is* such a huge task - especially if you already have nested lookarrounds.

Comment: I guess you mean look ahead, but how is that not a negation? This is the exact idea of `!(A v B) = (?!(?:A|B))`, in regex language. You have to make up the pattern you want to avoid anyway.

Comment: I see what you mean. But all you have to do is throw away all regex not fitting your criteria, then match everything: `(?!(?:A|B)).*`

Comment: @Robin: okay, so demorgan says: `!!A = A`, right? Is `16` and `(?!(?!16).*).*` equal? I bet the last one also matches `161` or `1625648svyxcv`...

Comment: But `(?!(?!16))` does equal `(?=16)`... I guess I get what you mean though, as it doesn't equal `16`: strictly speaking, you may be right about the nature of regex not fully supporting negation. In this example it is though perfectly appropriate to use look around, that ARE supporting negation, to filter cases.

Comment: @Robin Maybe my post was to "short" for that. Ofc. negative Lookahead can be used as *kind of a* negation for many cases. But the nature of a **real** negation is, that it is 100% reversable by applying it twice - which is not 100% true for a lookahead. Therefore "negativ lookahead != negation" (Reductio ad absurdum)